# How to open and run terminal and install driver for Broadcom 802.g wireleiss

Tags: installation, drivers

I'm new to Ubuntu and can't find a way to just open and execute the driver.  I tried to download the driver, had to use windows to download and then transfer it to a usb drive, then i right clicked on the file, went to properties and allowed it to be executed as a program.  The check mark disappeared as soon as I hit the box, and the file I noticed, was marked read only.  I tried read and write, but that didn't work either.

What do I do now?  BTW, I do not know how to run Terminal, or even what that is, I am that new, and I'm stuck, switching back and forth between windows and ubuntu.

Help!

Comment: To open terminal
press ctrl+alt+t

if your driver is in .tar.gz format ,just extract it and follow the instructions in the readme file

Answer (score 1):

I assume that You are using Ubuntu 11.10.

Terminal can be opened from the Dash home by typing terminal in the search box and pressing enter.

Good instructions for installing the drivers for Broadcom 802.g can be found from here: http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#Ubuntu.2FDebian

EDIT: I just realized that you propably can't get in the web without this driver to follow these instructions. There seems to be instructions for offline case: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43%20-%20No%20Internet%20access

Comment: I've tried looking for the read me file in the tar.gz format drivers folder.  I don't have one.  This is really labor intensive as I have to reboot and switch back and forth between Vista and Ubuntu to try to work it all out.  Anywhere I can go to download a simpler driver?